# Solving Knapsack using Dyanamic Programming

Tags: python, algorithm

I was implementing the snippet of Knapsack problem using the algorithm that i found in this link [Knapsack Problem](http://www.es.ele.tue.nl/education/5MC10/Solutions/knapsack.pdf)

I have also attached the snippet of the algorithm here too. [image: Knapsack Algorithm]

I have written following python snippet for the algorithm. Here it is:

```
def knapsack(v,w,n,W):
    V = [[None for x in range(W+1)] for x in range(len(v)+1)]

    for wy in range(W+1):
        V[0][wy] = 0

    for i in range(1,n+1):
        for wx in range(W+1):
            # print i,wx
            if w[i] <= wx:

                V[i][wx] = max(V[i-1][wx], v[i]+V[i-1][wx-w[i]])
            else:
                V[i][wx] = V[i-1][wx]
    return V[n][W]

print knapsack(v = [10,40,30,50],w=[5,4,6,3],n=4,W=10)
```

I am supposed to get output **90** at position **[4,9]** . What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Your code raises an IndexError at `if w[i] <= wx` line. Are you sure you posted the working code?

Comment: I have written the code just according to the algorithm above. The code is giving index error this means i accessed the list value which doesn't exist. But correct me if there is something wrong in my code.

Comment: Please don't chain questions together unless they're directly related to solving the original problem. Ask a new question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure but i think the error is

- Elements `v and w` are 0-based index(0 to n-1)
- You are iterating in the range `1 to n`
- So `w[n]` or `v[n]` will throw `IndexError`

**Updated CODE:**

```
def knapsack(v,w,n,W):
    V = [[None for x in range(W+1)] for x in range(len(v)+1)]

    for wy in range(W+1):
        V[0][wy] = 0

    for i in range(1,n+1):
        for wx in range(W+1):
            # print i,wx
            if w[i-1] <= wx:

                V[i][wx] = max(V[i-1][wx], v[i-1]+V[i-1][wx-w[i-1]])
            else:
                V[i][wx] = V[i-1][wx]
    return V[n][W]

print knapsack(v = [10,40,30,50],w=[5,4,6,3],n=4,W=10)
```

The output is now `90`.

[image: Output of the above code]

Check the results at [Ideone](http://ideone.com/sn4a5g)