# Knapsack using Dyanmic Programming Fails to give correct answer

Tags: python, algorithm, knapsack-problem

I was implementing the snippet of Knapsack problem using the algorithm that i found in this link [Knapsack Problem](http://www.es.ele.tue.nl/education/5MC10/Solutions/knapsack.pdf)

I asked the question earlier on Stack Overflow, where's I was having problem in getting output from the return statement of program. You can check that here [Previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22423507/solving-knapsack-using-dyanamic-programming)

I have also attached the snippet of the algorithm here too. [image: Knapsack Algorithm]

I have written following python snippet for the algorithm. Here it is:

```
def knapsack(v,w,n,W):
    V = [[None for x in range(W+1)] for x in range(len(v)+1)]
    keep = [[0 for x in range(W+1)] for x in range(len(v)+1)]
    # print keep

    for wy in range(W+1):
        V[0][wy] = 0

    for i in range(1,n+1):
        for wx in range(W+1):
            # print i,wx
            if w[i-1] <= wx:

                V[i][wx] = max(V[i-1][wx], v[i-1]+V[i-1][wx-w[i-1]])
                keep[i][wx] = 1
            else:
                V[i][wx] = V[i-1][wx]
                keep[i][wx] = 0
    K = W
    # print keep
    for i in range(n,0,-1):
        if keep[i][K] == 1:
            print i
            K = K - w[i-1]

    return V[n][W]

print knapsack(v = [10,40,30,50], w=[5,4,6,3],n=4,W=10)
```

I am supposed to get **4,2** as my value, but getting **4,3** . Please correct where I'm going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Problems in if statament:

```
        if w[i-1] <= wx:

            V[i][wx] = max(V[i-1][wx], v[i-1]+V[i-1][wx-w[i-1]])
            keep[i][wx] = 1
        else:
            V[i][wx] = V[i-1][wx]
            keep[i][wx] = 0
```

if `(w[i-1] <= wx) and (v[i-1]+V[i-1][wx-w[i-1]] <= V[i-1][wx])` you are doind

```
            V[i][wx] = max(V[i-1][wx], v[i-1]+V[i-1][wx-w[i-1]])
            keep[i][wx] = 1
```

but you should

```
            V[i][wx] = V[i-1][wx]
            keep[i][wx] = 0
```